# How can I place the output of a print statement also into the users clipboard

Tags: python, python-3.7

Question Answered Working Now.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyperclip
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for x in f:
        pyperclip.copy(convertto_RLE(f.readline().rstrip('\n')))
```

Comment: I would recommend that you add some explanatory text to your answer, or you risk having it deleted as 'low quality' (even though it may be a correct answer)!

Answer (score 0):

you can use pbcopy on unix system

```py
import os

f = open(file, "r")
for x in file:
    ln = convertto_RLE(f.readline().rstrip('\n'))
    os.system("echo '%s' | pbcopy" % ln)
    print(ln)
```